# Unable to install R packages in spotfire analyst

Tags: spotfire, terr

I'm using Spotfire Analyst v10.4. I'm writing data functions in Spotfire which require specific R packages. I've tried installing packages from TERR console and from TERR package management. I am an admin user and every time I get the same error :  "Error in unzip(zipFile): Error calling zip command". Any help appreciated on how to solve this.

[image]

Comment: I tried to install the same package and had no problem. Have you installed other packages successfully in the past? I suggest opening a support ticket. There might be a problem with your installed (in Spotfire) TERR modules.

Comment: I'm unable to install any of the packages. I've raised a support ticket too but they also are unable to solve as of now, it's been a week. I reinstalled my spotfire and TERR modules, I don't think of any problem there.

Comment: what is the exact version of TERR you have?

Comment: sorry, probably not the right question. Funnily, I just had the same problem, but in my case it was fixed by removing the TERR file from the modules folder and letting Spotfire reinstall it when I re-opened the client. So I think you need to insist with support.

Comment: My TERR version is 5.0.0.66. I'll try your method as well. The support doesn't seem to figure out as well. It's been 2 weeks and I've got no sols from them :/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the "vctrs" package, which was returning the same error (not being able to unzip the file) by copying the package from the R folder and placing it in the TERR folder, along with the other packages. As soon as I tried to install it again in Spotfire it recognized that it was there already and I could continue my analysis.